# How to build multi dimention collection in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I would like to build a collection like this:

```
a1 =>
   *name1
   b1 => aaa
   b2 => bbb
a2 =>
   *name2
   c1 => ccc
   c2 => ddd
```

How can I acomplish this using Laravel Collections? I tried many combinations of put and push but it didn't work out.

Comment: What exactly did you try?  Pushing a collection, array, or object should work.

Comment: During iteration I want to create a collection. I don't have all the data at once. And the extra thing is the name property for a1 and a2. As long as I use push it puts elements one on another - not inside of them (b1 inside a1 and so on.)